# How to add horizontal scrollbar to only one column in QTreeView

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I've did some digging but didn't found an answer anywhere.
How could I add horizontal scrollbar for only one column out of 3 existing in QTreeView?

Comment: That is not possible out of the box using `QTreeView` (or any other standard Qt view). If the text is too long to fit in a column, text elision could be used in combination with a tooltip showing the whole text. Scrolling may be possible by implementing a custom item delegate and a custom scroll bar to scroll all items at once.